# Open invisible download url (and after download, close it)

Tags: batch-file, browser, download, invisible

Here's my problem :
Since 2016, I make some bots that we need to manually do UPDATE, and now, with some code in the .bat, the bot can do a UPDATE alone, but he open the browser and after download the file, he didn't close it.

I wanted to use ByteTransfer in Powershell or curl, but the download link like that: `"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=4DJ8skd91lp"` (ByteTransfer and curl need a download link like this: `"http://myserver.com/file.ext"`).

What I want it's to open INVISIBLE BROWSER to download the file and close it after *(only the invisible browser, for client didn't have to get f#cked by the UPDATE)*.

I could use Iexplorer, but the download need a confirm, and the bot (.bat) can't detect if the download are waiting 'cus need confirm.

So, can we download a file in a url without a ".ext, .bat, .txt" in the end and without disturbing the client? Like some application that's do UPDATE ?

Thank's for answer.

Comment: I removed your MS-DOS tag and reference, if you really are using MS-DOS, _(last version 6.22 was released 23 years ago)_, then please add the tag back.

Comment: Why should curl or PowerShells `Invoke-Webrequest` have a problem with that url? See `curl --help` and guess what the `-o` or `--output` options is for?

Comment: @LotPings for PowerShell I tried to do that with ByteTransfer, it's not work.

Comment: @Compo I use the default program on windows that execute .bat files. well, it's not "MS-DOS" I think, the last version was 8.0, 17 years ago.

Comment: @LotPings I tried in "cmd" that -> powershell Invoke-Webrequest "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bzi8QXTGV1P2d3kwczRMp0hZV2M"
But with the "&" in url, it didn't work.
And if I do that -> powershell Invoke-Webrequest "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download"&"id=0Bzi8QXTGV1P2d3kwczRMp0hZV2M"
He just open "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download" and do "id=0Bzi8QXTGV1P2d3kwczRMp0hZV2M" in cmd like a command.

Comment: You've to put the command in double quotes and escape the url double quotes with a backslash. `powershell -NoP -c "iwr \"https://...\" "`

Comment: @LotPings I tried that : powershell Start-BitsTransfer -source "'http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bzi8QXTGV1P2d3kwczRMc0hZV2M'" -destination "'C:\Users\Reizod\Downloads\Test.t'"
There're no syntax error, but now the error is "Le service est temporairement surchargé".
I'll try for powershell -NoP -c "iwr \"https://...\" ".

Comment: @LotPings the command work but he didn't download the file.

Comment: I don't have always all answers, but a computer with an internet connection to do research, what is expected from every questioner. [This link](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)  might interest you.

Comment: @LotPings thank's you for the link, I'll try these ways.

Comment: in cmd : powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "'%URL%'" -OutFile "'%OUTPUT%'"
It's work, thank's you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to LotPings, using Powershell in cmd, this command download the file in URL without confirm and without opening the browser :
powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "'%URL%'" -OutFile "'%OUTPUT%'"

CMD use (") and powershell use (').
just need in the cmd to :
set url=https://...
set output=%systemdrive%...